# How to stop playing the videoView when Fragment with ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android-viewpager

I want to stop a videoView playing in a fragment when the fragment is change.
When i change the fragment the video is still playing.

Here is the code for Main Activity

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentStepOne(), "1");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentStepTwo(), "2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {

        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mFragmentList.size();
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
```

And here is the Fragment Class

```
public class FragmentStepOne extends Fragment{

public FragmentStepOne() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


VideoView video;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step_two, container, false);

   video = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getActivity().getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.video);
    video.setVideoURI(uri);

    MediaController mc=new MediaController(getContext());
    mc.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(mc);
    video.requestFocus();



    return rootView;
}
```

Thank you in advance.